# How to force an app to use a specific graphics card?

Tags: graphics-card, windows-11

##### My PC:

- **CPU/APU:** AMD Ryzen 5 5600g *(comes with integrated graphics card)*
- **Graphics card:** NVIDIA RTX 3060
- **RAM:** 32GB
- **Motherboard:** MSI B550M Pro VDH WiFi
- **OS:** Windows 11

I'm trying to record face cam using 'snapcamera' app on integrated graphics card and leave my RTX 3060 for gaming and recording the gameplay.

I want to use snapcamera on integrated card, because it will take some load off the dedicated card, because snapcamera takes a noticeable amount of usage on graphics card.

I tried to set it under 'System > Display > Graphics' settings, but it doesn't work. Although this method is working fine for all other apps, but sadly not for snap camera.

##### What can I do regarding this?

Comment: If you can't use the usual settings then probably it can't be done.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Is there no other way to do this? I know this app can run fine with integrated graphics, because I was using it before buying RTX 3060 a few days ago.

Comment: Do you have a screen connected to your integrated GPU's connector? Can this be solved simply by doing that?

Comment: @music2myear I don't have a second monitor, so I can't verify that.

Comment: So you want the internal GPU to process this application and then pass these results through the discrete GPU?

Comment: @music2myear I want the internal GPU to handle the complex processing of application, and save the recording to a file. Thing is this method is working fine for other apps like DroidCam or Camo. But it's not working for snapcamera.

Comment: It may be doing you a favor inadvertently by *not* using the iGPU (some software is coded to use the best hardware even when not needed)... The thing is the app you're complaining about has pretty ridiculous, by today's standards, graphics requirements (Intel HD Graphics 4000/ Nvidia GeForce 710/ AMD Radeon HD 6450) so it CAN'T take a *noticeable amount of usage on graphics card*, it just can't. OTOH, it requires a fair amount of RAM - 4GB - (note: NOT VRAM, *system* RAM) so that might be somehow giving you a false perception.

Comment: @ChanganAuto It's not doing me any favor, only giving me headache, because this app was working more than fine on my pc when I didn't have dedicated card. So, Integrated card of 5600g is more than capable to run it, I'm sure of it. ALSO, I've seen in HWINFO and Task manager, that it was using 35-45% of my dedicated GPU and not the RAM.